# How to make post on Facebook using Selenium Webdriver + Java?

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, webdriver

How to make post on Facebook using Selenium Webdriver + Java?

This window. http://prntscr.com/i603dv

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("me-email");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("my-password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='loginbutton']")).click();
//here I turn off notifications        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@action='cancel']")).click();

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
//with help of this code I can focus on window.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"uiIconText _5qtp\"])[1]"));
actions.doubleClick(element);

//Here I want to post text, but it doesn't work.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"_1mf _1mj\"]")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Why it doesn't work? Then I press button Post but it doesn't work also.

Comment: You won't get much of a response just asking "why doesn't it work", post a stack trace if you have an error or at the very least describe what the error is. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: Use the API. Facebook doesn't allow you to do it in any other automated way

Comment: @WizKid thanks for the advice, but this is test project for job interview. Task is to do it on Selenium WebDriver + Java

Comment: So the company require you to do something that would go against Facebook Terms of Service and may get your account banned?

Comment: @WizKid turns out to be so.

Comment: @president You may be liable to be questioned and you may land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468)

Answer (score 0):

The popup/window opens after double click . So you could try to switch to new popup using switch  to window of webdriver. It should help . 
Here is a link of simple webdriver test which switch window 
http://learn-automation.com/handle-multiple-windows-in-selenium-webdriver/

Try to do the same for you .
If you have any questions let me know .

Comment: This is the exception I get: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//span[@class=\"uiIconText _5qtp\"])[1]"}

Comment: I cannot locate element, although I tried many options. Still cannot.

Comment: Did you try to swich to new window ?

Comment: This window doesn't open now. I don't know the reason. It just cannot locate it when it's in this state: http://prntscr.com/i61d57

Comment: I will try to run this code , to understand the reason

Comment: I was able to do it. The problem was in Chrome. I found information on the internet that it has bug. I tried with Firefox and it worked!

Comment: Congrats )). Good job

Answer (score 0):

"_1mf _1mj " is a complex class. Selenium won't work on complex classes.

You can try Action chain - press  "tab" button multiple times until you reach to "post"

Also, Facebook provides a drop down option after pressing tab button . You can choose from the drop down what you want to do., Using selenium.

Alternatively try mbasic version of FB.